# Can see custom font on server, but not locally

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I am using Sansation as custom font, and it shows fine when I upload my site, but when I debug locally, it ain't showing:

Default.css:

```
/* #region Fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Sansation Regular";
    src: url("/Fonts/Sansation_Regular.eot?") format("eot"), url("/Fonts/Sansation_Regular.woff") format("woff"), url("/Fonts/Sansation_Regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/Fonts/Sansation_Regular.svg#SansationRegular") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
/* #endregion */

body {
    font-family: "Sansation Regular";
}
```

The Fonts are located in:

```
root:
   -Shared:
   ---Assets:
   ------CSS:
   ---------Default.css
   ------Fonts:
   ---------Sansation_Regular.xxx
```

How can I get the fonts to show locally too?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on, e.g. `http://foo.com/bar/hello.html`, and you encounter a *URI* with the form `/Fonts/world.ttf`, it refers to the *URL* `http://foo.com/Fonts/world.ttf`.

From your data structure, it looks like the *URI* to point to your font should have the form `/Shared/Assets/Fonts/world.ttf` to result in a *URL* like `http://foo.com/Shared/Assets/Fonts/world.ttf`

If you open up your developer console and look at network activity, you should see the wrong path in attempted/failing resource loads.

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but that still didn't work (`/Shared/Assets/Fonts/world.ttf`). I just tried: `../Fonts/Sansation_Regular.ttf` and it worked. But thanks.